# Resgatar número de telefone do usuário

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, typescript

No Android, usando Java, é possível resgatar o número de telefone do usuário do dispositivo com o seguinte código:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.
     getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String numero = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

É possível regatar o número do usuário usando Ionic + Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a lib [SIM](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sim/) do `ionic-native`.
Exemplo:

```
 getInformacoesSIM() {
    this.sim.requestReadPermission().then(() => {
      this.sim.getSimInfo().then((info) => {
        console.log(info);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }, () => console.log('Permission denied'))
  }
```

Se preferir evitar o encadeamento das promises, você também pode usar o [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)

```
 async getInformacoesSIM() {
    try {
      let permission = await this.sim.requestReadPermission();
      let info = await this.sim.getSimInfo();
      console.log(info);
    } catch (er) {
      console.log(er);
    }
  }
```

De acordo com a documentação, no retorno você tera o seguinte `payload`:

```
{
  "carrierName": "Android",
  "countryCode": "us",
  "mcc": "310",
  "mnc": "260",
  "phoneNumber": "15555215554",
  "deviceId": "0000000000000000",
  "simSerialNumber": "89014103211118510720",
  "subscriberId": "310260000000000",
  "callState": 0,
  "dataActivity": 0,
  "networkType": 3,
  "phoneType": 1,
  "simState": 5,
  "isNetworkRoaming": false
}
```

> OBS: the content of phoneNumber is unreliable (see this and this
>   article). Sometimes phoneNumber is only an empty string.

De acordo com o `README.txt` da lib, nem todos os telefones estão "aptos" a retornar o numero do telefone, nesses casos o phoneNumber será representado por uma string vazia.

Comment: Eu estava tentando exatamente assim, porém no meu smartphone estava retornando vazio. Sendo assim, eu achei que eu estava fazendo algo errado. Quando debuguei, ai percebi o que de fato estava retornando. Vlw por responder. =D